# Overriding Abstract Fields Java

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, encapsulation

I have an abstract class which has a method used by all classes that extend the class. That method is identical for each class so I don't want to have to write it over and over in those classes. The problem is that the method uses 2 variables that are declared in each class. I can't have the method in the abstract class without having those variables int eh abstract class. But if I do that, they take on the value specified in the abstract class, not the classes that extend it. How can I fix this?

Example code:

```
public abstract class Example {
   public String property1 = ""
   public String property2 = ""
    public ArrayList<String> getPropertyies() {
        ArrayList<String> propertyList = new ArrayList<>();
        propertyList.add(property1);
        propertyList.add(property2);
        return property1;
    }
}

public class ExampleExtension extends Example {
    public String property1 = "this is the property";
    public String property2 = "this is the second property";
}
```

Comment: What is a Java `"abstract field"`?

Comment: That is a **very** bad coding pattern. Any good IDE will tell you that `ExampleExtension.property1` is *hiding* `Example.property1`. Keep it up if you hate people who read your code, incl. yourself.

Comment: That same comment can be said nicely. Please comment with some respect and integrity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should limit the scope of the fields to `private` in the abstract class and declare a constructor for populating the values:

```
public abstract class Example {
    private final String property1;
    private final String property2;

    protected Example(String property1, String property2) {
        this.property1 = property1;
        this.property2 = property2;
    }
    //...
}
```

Subclasses would then initialize the field values in their constructors by calling the `super` constructor:

```
public class ExampleExtension extends Example {

    public ExampleExtension() {
        super("value1", "value2");
        // initialize private fields of ExampleExtension, if any
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why should we initialize property1 and property2 of `Example` (`super("value1", "value2");`)? Does `ExampleExtension` have these fields and what will be their values?

Comment: `ExampleExtension` "has" the fields because it extends `Example`. But it doesn't have direct read/write access because of the `private` visibility. If you need to read the values of the fields from the extending class, you can add a getter for them in the super class.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, these private fields must be initialized in constructor. Because they are not defined again in `ExampleExtension`, they exist in `Example` and can be accessed with getter.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to override the variables. You can set the initial values of your properties in the constructor:

```
public class ExampleExtension extends Example {

    public ExampleExtension() {
        property1 = "this is the property";
        property2 = "this is the second property";
    }

}
```

A better way is to use a constructor with parameters though, as Mick Mnemonic suggest in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

IMO Mick's solution is the most pragmatic, although note that you also have the option to make the properties abstract, and then use subclass polymorphicism to require that subclasses override the property implementation:

```
public abstract class Example {
   public abstract String getProperty1();
   public abstract String getProperty2();

    public ArrayList<String> getPropertyies() {
        ArrayList<String> propertyList = new ArrayList<>();
        propertyList.add(getProperty1());
        propertyList.add(getProperty2());
        return propertyList;
    }
}

public class ExampleExtension extends Example {
    public String getProperty1() { return "this is the property"};
    public String getProperty2() { return "this is the second property"};
}
```

Comment: When we write `abstract String`, it will show error: "Modifier 'abstract' not allowed here".

Answer (score 0):

Make what differs(e.g. property1,property2)  abstract method in this case . Search for related reading on template pattern

```
public abstract class Example {
       public ArrayList<String> getPropertyies() {
        ArrayList<String> propertyList = new ArrayList<>();
        propertyList.add(getProperty1());
        propertyList.add(getProperty2());
        return property1;
    }

    public abstract getProperty1();//overriden by other class that has diff value for property1
    public abstract getProperty2();//overriden by other class that has diff value for property2
}
```